# Navigation links server side rendering in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm still new to nextjs and i'm building static site, i'm trying to make server responsible for rendering navigation links but i can't figure this yet how to do this and how to fetch those links

as you know navigation links lies in seperate component and not included in every page and also fetching data must be in nextPage not in the components

the only solution i have is to fetch navigation links when home page loads and then get the navigation links as props and pass it the context but this will make the client responsible for rendering the naviagtion

my _app.js is

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import { Layout } from '../components'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

as you see the Layout contains the navigation and Component has the rest

Comment: you can find the detailed answer to your question in this [ Footer / Header loading via API only once, server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431077/next-js-footer-header-loading-via-api-only-once-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

The global data should come from the layout, not from the page. If you have more than one page, you don't want to repeat your API calls in each pages.

If you use the nextjs 13 (still in beta atm), you can do this in the `app/` directory. If you don't, you will need to use `useSwr` in your layout : https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts.

To summarize, if you really want to be client agnostic on this feature, i think you need to try nextjs 13.

Comment: so you are saying that the only solution is a client side rendering for navigation and footer if i excluded the new /app directory approach

Comment: you can do that in each page but it's not the best way to do it. It will force u to put the layout components (header & footer) in the page itself, loosing all the concept of common layout.